# Handling Encrypted Response and Request

Tags: jmeter

With the tool Jmeter, I am facing some issues in that so I need help from you. The script which I have recorded, having all the values in the encrypted form of Boday data[POST] request. And the response is also in encrypted format. So I am not able to correlate and parameterize that values because only encrypted value is passing through request. Nothing else is passing in a request like plain text. Even If I implement the encryption algorithm then how to catch values from response?  Will you please take the time to look into this? How can it be solved?

Comment: Try viewing the response under View Result Tree. Select "Document" from drop down and see if the response changes.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box JMeter can only encrypt strings via [__digest()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) function, if it supports the algorithm used by the application you're testing you will be able to use it for encryption of the request parameters.

With regards to decryption, you can add a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and implement the decryption logic in [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/). Once you perform the decryption you will be able to replace original (encrypted) response with the decrypted one, like:

```
byte [] encryptedResponse = prev.getResponseData()
// your code here to decrypt the response
prev.setResponseData(decryptedResponse)
```

and the decrypted data will be usable in other PostProcessors, [Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) and [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html)